# How to import "stompjs/lib/stomp.min" in angular2-webpack

Tags: angular, websocket, webpack, stomp

I have an angular2-webpack app , want to implements stomp,sockjs-client,websocket.

have added **"sockjs": "0.3.18",
    "stompjs": "2.3.3"** in package.json.

when write like this in a service :

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import { Client, Message, Stomp } from 'stompjs/lib/stomp.min';
```

there is an err:

```
can't find name "Client",
can't find name "Message",
can't find name "Stomp",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect this code to work? Did you find an example with this syntax somewhere? The `Stomp` object only contains a lowercase [`client`](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/blob/master/lib/stomp.js#L461-L483), and nothing else from your list.

Just do

```
import Stomp from 'stompjs';
```

And follow [the instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompjs) for making a client.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a specialized version for Angular https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs (npm @stomp/ng2-stompjs).

It works well with Webpack, Rollup, RxJS and other newer libraries/tool-chain.